# Secure Access Module (SAM) connected directly to MCU bypassing the reader IC

Tags: embedded, digital-communications, rfid, nfc, soc

I have been trying to design an NFC Reader using a Quectel SC60 module with a Secure Access Module (SAM) interface.

The problem is that in the reference design, the SAM is connected directly to the SoC bypassing the reader itself.

I am not sure how is it going to work. I mean, the SAM has to be connected to the tranceiver IC for the data, right?

The relevant links are as follows:

[NFC deference design](http://183.82.99.162:8000/Quectel/LTE%20Module/SC60/02%20Hardware/Quectel_SC60_NFC_Reference_Design_Rev.A_20180420.pdf)

[Datasheets and other details of SC60](https://www.quectel.com/ProductDownload/SC60.zip)

Comment: It seems like you are trying to get us to do this design project for you. You should make a stronger effort to learn about this yourself, and then ask a more specific question.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson ! With all due respect, although it is true that the project is in design phase, it isn't true that I haven't done my part of the research. Yes, it is true that I am a beginner but I have designed a NFC Reader before where the SAM was connected to the Reader. And I have been searching through the net for days for a design where SAM is directly connected to the MCU and not to the Reader but couldn't find any explanation before asking a question here.And I think my question is pretty direct"How can SAM be connected to the MCU and not the Reader.From where it will take data then?"

Comment: OK, can you tell me where I can find the "SAM" on the linked NFC reference design?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson ! Thanks for considering to help.  Okay, I get what you are saying. But according to my(limited) understanding, physically a SAM card can either be a SIM card and plugged into a SAM slot in a reader, or a fixed integrated circuit in a housing directly soldered on a Printed circuit board. So, I guess , I would call the **Main (U)SIM SLOT  as the  SECURE ACCESS MODULE(SAM)**  slot which is on **Page 7**.

Comment: Please don't use mysterious 3 letter abbreviations. SAM could be Atmel SAM family of microcontrollers, surface to air missiles or a hobbit from Lord of the Rings. Or apparently some card standard...

Answer (score 0):

The two things are simply different peripherals. The SC60 is basically a mobile phone in a package; in order to connect to a network, it needs a SIM, and connections for that are provided externally.

*Separately*, this document describes how you can connect an NFC reader, which presumably shows up as a peripheral to the software somehow. But it has nothing to do with the SIM.

Comment: ! I think I may have found the answer. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Wire_Protocol) , I think they are using the **SWP** protocol.

Comment: But ,thanks anyways for understanding the question and trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The SAM has 2 differents topologies of use: SAM-S mode and SAM-X mode. In the SAM-S mode you communicate with the SAM in standalone mode; all comunication is across the SoC/Uc. In the SAM-X mode the SAM is connected directly to the tranceiver IC.

https://community.nxp.com/t5/NFC/SAM-module-in-the-SAM-S-vs-SAM-X-mode/m-p/650463.

For more information about the SAM of NXP you need to contact NXP directly since this information is classified and protected by NDA. All the information and commands are in the classified datasheet.